# Is it possible to attach an event to a custom collection and modify the ui on changes to the collection?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Let's say, for example, I have a class called Error, and properties of 'Error' include ErrorMessage, ErrorCode, etc. When a new instance of Error has been created, the instance is added to a collection, ErrorCollection:ICollection. Would it be possible to change the UI once it's added? If so, how can this be done without causing problems with Threads

Note: an instance of the Error class would be created asynchronously.

Crude visual example:

```
public class ErrorCollection:ICollection<Error>
    {
        private readonly ICollection<Error> _collection = new Collection<Error>();
        public EventArgs e = null;
        public void Add(Error item)
        {
            _collection.Add(item);
            if(AddEventHandler != null)
            {
                AddEventHandler(this, e);
            }
        }
        public event EventHandler AddEventHandler;
        public void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do some more stuff here including updating UI
        }
        ...
    }
```

```
public class Error
    {
        public Error()
        {                        
        }

        private Task<Error> InitializeErrorAsync()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Do some stuff that can take a while
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                return this;
            });            
        }

        public static async Task<Error> CreateError()
        {
            Error error = new Error();
            return await error.InitializeErrorAsync();
        }
    }
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ErrorCollection errorCollection = new ErrorCollection();        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            errorCollection.AddEventHandler += new EventHandler(errorCollection.OnAdd);                        
        }
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            errorCollection.Add(await Error.CreateError());            
        }
    }
```

Edit:  Let me also clarify, in my example, I was using Error as an example class. Not to say I won't use it for Errors, but I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: Why are you not using ObservableCollection with BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization?

Comment: In what way? And how would that be any different than using ICollection with an event attached to the add function? From my understanding, you would use ObservableCollection if you wanted to display the collection in a table where the properties of the collection would bind to the columns. In my case, I would like to update certain parts of the UI

Comment: It would notify about collection changes. That's what collections do that implement INotifyCollectionChanged, like ObservableCollection. Any ItemsControl that has its ItemsSource bound to such a collection updates automatically. But you could as well manually attach a CollectionChanged event handler. No need to reinvent this.

Comment: I see. ItemControl isn't limited to tables but can be just a group of elements. But because Im using a collection of objects as an ItemsSource how can binding work? Based on my example in the question, the Error class would contain members that would be used in the binding (i.e {Binding ErrorMessage}). How does the logic work for the application to know to use the last added Error to the ErrorCollection? I imagine ItemControl.ItemsSource = ErrorCollection.Last() and when ErrorCollection registers a change, it will automatically update the ItemContol.ItemsSource. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

there is a class that notifies the viewmodel and the model whenever errors occur it also allows the ui to know an then it changes apparence regarding that
check this post
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

Comment: Seems similar to the INotifyCollectionChange, which is something an ObservableCollection uses. I thought of using that, but I don't need it for DataBindings which is why I opted for implementing ICollection. Let me also clarify, in my example, I was using Error as an example class. Not to say I won't use it for Errors but I'm looking for a general solution. I will modify my question to reflect this.

Comment: you can just make a property that follows the size of the collection or something like that and that update the UI based on the results

Comment: and that's really what the event is for, right? the problem I have is the implementation of this process correctly. I can't understand how it should be done without running into problems, including locking the application

Answer (score 0):

By using an ObservableCollection instead of ICollection. ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged, which can be used in combination with ItemsSource to update the UI when the collection changes automatically. No need to use events to reinvent this, as Clemens pointed out